# Необычное употребление личного местоимения

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

В чем заключается особенность употребления личного местоимения в предложении "После того как ее мужа сжигают на костре, Анжелика находит убежище у разбойников"?

P. S. Задание из Высшей Пробы (олимпиады Высшей школы экономики), там речь именно о личном местоимении, а в ответах указано именно это предложение: http://vfl.ru/fotos/5035445814668307.html.

Answer (score 3):

> В чем заключается особенность употребления личного местоимения в
>   предложении *"После того как ее мужа сжигают на костре, Анжелика
>   находит убежище у разбойников"?*

Но почему Вы остановили свой выбор именно на этом предложении?

В задании ведь было приведено пять предложений. И вопрос звучал так:

> В каком описании фильма личное местоимение употреблено достаточно
>   необычным образом?

Я думаю, речь могла идти об этом предложении:

> *1) Жизнь Натали стремительно меняется, когда рядом с **ней** появляется странный юноша по имени Кит.*

В чем заключается особенность употребления этого местоимения?

В рассматриваемом предложении имеются два существительных женского рода: ***жизнь*** и ***Натали***. Есть некоторая неясность: какое из этих существительных замещено местоимением ***ней*** в придаточном?

См.: *"Рядом с ней появляется странный юноша…"* С кем с ней? Рядом с жизнью? Рядом с Натали?

Похоже на то, что рассматриваемое предложение составлено с некоторым нарушением этого [**правила:**](http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=96022d3f-11b6-46f9-bbbd-a27c61e8e165)

> Если предложение содержит несколько существительных мужского или
>   женского рода, то недопустимо в последующем предложении использовать
>   местоимения *он, она, его, её.*

В предложении (1) это правило нарушено.

Comment: slava1947, но ведь в №5 случай ещё более вопиющий. №1 еще можно понять, поскольку жизнь - не есть одушевленное и, соответственно, лицо действующее. А в №5 - идет речь о двух ***людях***, субъектах,  причем "ненужный" субъект стоит ближе к местоимению.

Comment: Даже если считать такое правило незыблемым, можно ли с уверенностью трактовать два как "несколько"? Ведь можно было однозначно потребовать "два или более".

Comment: @Alex_ander: _...можно ли с уверенностью трактовать два как "несколько"?_  === Это не я так правило сформулиромал, а авторы вот этого учебника (может, и не сами придумали, а откуда-то взяли): http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/777-25_mestoimenie.html === И в приводимом в учебнике примере они не делают различий между "два" и "несколько". Я лишь постарался корректно процитировать их учебник.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно вначале идет имя, а потом местоимение, его заменяющее. Здесь наоборот.

Ой... А где здесь личное местоимение?! "Её" — это притяжательное местоимение.

Comment: В Высшей Пробе именно так: http://vfl.ru/fotos/5035445814668307.html

Comment: *Здесь наоборот.* - Если читать с конца, то да, будет необычно. А так - все нормально.

Comment: До нормального это исправляется простой перестановкой местоимения с именем: _После того как мужа Анжелики сжигают на костре, она находит убежище у разбойников_.

Comment: Не является ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, что такое "высшая проба" (судя по всему что-то совсем не авторитетное для подобных ссылок, вы бы хоть источник указывали более содержательно), но из пяти пунктов на картинке я бы выбрала последний.

Если же ответ действительно 2), то, видимо, автор хотел что-то такое построить по поводу омонимичности форм личного и притяжательного местоимения. Но сделано это крайне неудачно.

Хотя нет, там же еще в двух случаях есть подобная омонимия... 
Да, скорее всего ответ таки 5) потому, что "Он" относится не к ближайшему существительному.

Что касается порядка следования существительного и местоимения, то не вижу ничего необычного.
В любом случае подобными пособиями пользоваться впредь не советую.

Кстати... №3 - очень коряво сформулирован. Получается, что он уже был одержим местью, когда там что-то ещё происходит.

Comment: "Высшая Проба" - олимпиада Высшей школы экономики. В ответах к этому заданию указано второе предложение. Я тоже не совсем понимаю, почему второе. Поэтому, собственно, и вопрос. Да, надо было содержательней, вы правы.

Comment: @AER На мой взгляд, ненормальны только предложения **2** и **3**. В третьем вышло, что до того, как человек оказался мёртвым, его брат уже был одержим местью за убийство. Про второе уже говорили (без упоминания имени в предшествующем тексте это если не ошибка, то плохой стиль); хуже этого только случай, когда после местоимения называют имя нового для повествования персонажа, на которого местоимением уже сослались - это из плохого перевода с английского.

Comment: *"Высшая Проба" - олимпиада Высшей школы экономики* - а зачем ВШЭ проводит олимпиады по русскому языку??? Не, я столько не выпью.(с)

Comment: При Вышке есть и Школа филологии, и Школа лингвистики. Например за этим.

Comment: Представляю тамошний уровень преподавания. Коль пироги начнет печи сапожник...