# Употребление слов-заместителей

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, местоимения

Нашёл правило:

> ...если предложение содержит несколько существительных мужского или женского рода, то недопустимо в последующем предложении использовать местоимения он, она, его, её.
>
> Так, в тексте: "В романе изображена женщина, увлечённая работой. Она нужна моим товарищам" – недопустимо употребление местоимение она, поскольку в предыдущем предложении есть два существительных женского рода: женщина, работа (https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/777-25_mestoimenie.html).

Но ведь иногда вполне понятно, на какое именно существительное ссылается местоимение: "В романе изображена женщина, увлечённая работой. Она сказала моим товарищам..." Очевидно, что сказать в этой ситуации может только женщина.

Вот ещё мой пример: «Вам необходимо будет отвечать на заявки от клиентов и консультировать их».

В том источнике:

> То же самое относится к использованию местоимений они, их, если предыдущий контекст содержит несколько существительных в форме множественного числа.
>
> Например, в сложном предложении: В этом сборнике опубликованы статьи педагогов, где они разбирают проблемы воспитания – двусмысленность от использования местоимения они создаётся потому, что в главном предложении употреблено два существительных – статьи, педагоги.

Имеет ли это правило категорический характер, или его следует применять только в тех случаях, когда возникает двусмысленность?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427737/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Итак, заходим на сайт https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/777-25_mestoimenie.html

Там очень много категоричных установок (недопустимо, грубейшая ошибка) и т.д. А вот примеры надуманные (вот что действительно недопустимо): "В романе изображена женщина, увлечённая работой. Она нужна моим товарищам". О чем это здесь?

При решении грамматических задач надо пользоваться не любыми, а **нормативными источниками**, к примеру, таким является справочник Розенталя  http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/20.htm

А там написано:

1. Местоимение 3-го лица (он, она, оно, они) обычно заменяет ближайшее к нему предшествующее существительное в форме того же рода и числа. **Однако эта связь местоимения с существительным определяется иногда смыслом, а не формально порядком слов**, например: Туристы побывали во многих городах страны: они интересовались прежде всего местными историческими достопримечательностями (**не вызывает сомнений, что местоимение они относится к более отдаленному существительному туристы**, а не к ближе стоящему городах).

**Возможность соотнесения местоимения с разными словами в предшествующем тексте может служить источником неясности или двусмысленности,** например: Сестра поступила в артистическую труппу, она скоро уезжает на гастроли (кто уезжает – сестра или труппа?). **В этих случаях необходима правка;**

Розенталь ясно говорит о том, когда нужна правка: **только для устранения неясности в конкретном тексте.**

И отсюда следует такое замечание: **а можно ли найти двусмысленность в текстовом примере, который вообще не имеет смысла?** Поэтому надо внимательно относиться  к тому, что нам предлагают в качестве примеров для разбора и для подтверждения каких-то теорий.

Поэтому  "правило не имеет категорического характера, его следует применять только в тех случаях, когда возникает двусмысленность".

Что касается различных учебных сайтов, то там должны быть **ссылки  на нормативные материалы.**

Comment: По-моему, это подводит теоретическую базу под мой ответ (см. выше).

Comment: @Sharon, авторы учебника, размещенного на сайте Лицей, доктора филологических наук.

Comment: @Серж Следует ли из этого,  что это доктор наук предлагает для анализа такой текст: "В романе изображена женщина, увлечённая работой. Она нужна моим товарищам".  Лично я в этом не уверена. С другой стороны, сайт не может давать рекомендации  по грамотной речи без учета нормативных источников, а сам сайт не может быть таким нормативным источником. Мне так кажется.  И еще мне кажется, что это вообще становится проблемой. Таких учебных сайтов много, материал в них дается весьма свободно, в авторском варианте, а заходящие люди принимают его за совершенную истину, которой необходимо следовать.

Comment: @М_Г Да, пожалуй,  у Вас и у Розенталя информация примерно одинаковая.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, нет ничего здоровее здравого смысла :). "В романе изображена женщина, увлечённая работой. Она сказала..." Кому не понятно, поднимите руки :).

Comment: Мы переходим на смайлики?

Answer (score 2):

Здесь все очень неоднозначно и зависит от контекста. Если речь шла о товарищах, которые безуспешно ищут работу, то местоимение "она" может относиться к работе. А если речь шла о товарищах, которые безуспешно ищут хорошую, добросовестную работницу, то местоимение "она" может относиться к женщине.
Для того, чтобы читателю не приходилось гадать, что же именно хотел сказать автор, подобного употребления местоимений все-таки лучше избегать.